# Chrome extension: adding bookmark with changed DOM

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension, which can make DOM manipulation, such as text bold or italic. After manipulating DOM, I want to add bookmark a current webpage with changed DOM. However, the changed DOM is not reflected to added bookmark.

There are two questions.

1. Is it possible to add bookmark with changed DOM?
2. If it is possible, how can I do that? Do I have to include cache or local storage Chrome API?

Please give me fruitful advice:)

Comment: You can't do it directly. You can add something to the URL like your extensionId=modified, declare a content script that runs on such URL patterns and reproduces the changes using some info from chrome.storage.local that you've saved there previously.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for you reply! could you explain more in detail? I am a newbee programmer, so it is difficult to catch up your answer.

Comment: Maybe someone else will. I think it's best to start with  documentation and demo extensions (also by debugging them in devtools) to gain both theoretical and practical knowledge.